# React Class Component this keyword Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'. TS2723

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react class component that has `this` being error with typescript because it's conditionally rendered, so `this` can be `null` or `undefined`. Other than using `@ts-ignore` is there a way around this? Thank you

Comment: Can you post the relevant snippet of code that is giving you this error?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to type props.children for some reason...